# Which groups may be obtained as $K$-homology groups?

Tags: cohomology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, noncommutative-topology

Recently I asked the following question, about the separability of the underlying $C^*$-algebra in the definition of $K$-homology:

> [mathoverflow.net/questions/181361](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181361/)

As far as I understood, in order to have well behaved theory (functoriality, six term exact sequence etc) we have to assume that our $C^*$-algebra is separable. This is in contrast with $K$-theory. Some time ago I asked also the following, natural question:

> [mathoverflow.net/questions/169270/](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/169270/)

So the natural continuation of those topics would be the following:

> **Question**: which groups may be obtained as $K$-homology groups for a separable $C^*$-algebra?

Comment: For C* algebras in the bootstrapclass it can be calculated using the universal coefficient theorem. Then one can observe for example that the K-homology of separable c*algebras can be uncountable..